# undefined method `with' for UserMailer:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can you help me with Mailer on Ruby?
gem 'mail_form', '~> 1.7', '>= 1.7.1'

I have this error

undefined method `with' for UserMailer:Class
Extracted source (around line #19):

```
if @user.save
   # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
   UserMailer.with(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_later
   # UserMailer.reject_timesheet(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_now
```

I tried this tutorial:
https://rubyonrailshelp.wordpress.com/2014/01/08/rails-4-simple-form-and-mail-form-to-make-contact-form/

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: I have followed the same blog that is working for me in rails 2.4.0

Comment: I assume you mean 4.2? I'm pretty sure the `with` method on ActionMailer was only introduced in version 5.

Answer (score 8):

```
UserMailer.with(user: @user).welcome_email.deliver_later
```

Above syntax supports in rails 5.2.

If you are using rails version below 5.2 you have to use below syntax

```
UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver_later
```